# Remove black background from copied and paste text in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have a weird black background from a text I copied and paste. Do you know how I can remove it?

[image]

I already tried something in Page setup ...

Comment: select all then click normal text

Answer (score 3):

I find an even better way: Format> Paragraph > margin and shadows and then white:

1. Select your text
2. 

[image]

3.
[image]

4. And select the color you want

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to repeat the copy/paste but instead of using default paste, use **paste only plain text**. The keyboard shortcut that works on US-EN, LA-SP keyboard layouts for PCs and maybe others is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. If the keybord shortcut doesn't work for you try using the Google Documents toolbar Edit menu or the contextual menu (right-click on the place that you want to add the text).

Comment: Thanks Ruben! Actually I find an even better way: Format> Paragraph > margin and shadows and then white!

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica You are welcome. I suggest you to post that as an answer.

Comment: In the 2023 Version of Google Docs: Format > Paragraph styles > Borders and shading --> set background to white.

Alternatively, if you want just the text, CTRL + SHIFT + V (on windows) or CMD + SHIFT + V (mac)